# use of static keyword in recursion in C

Tags: c

I am currently solving a program on [Russian Peasant algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Egyptian_multiplication) and i am using a recursive code:

My Code:

```
int russian_peasant(int a,int b)
{
    static int sum =0;
    if(a>=1)
    {
        if(a%2!=0)
        {
            sum += (b);
            russian_peasant(a/2,b*2);
        }
        else
        { 

            russian_peasant(a/2,b*2);
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n",sum);
    return sum;
}
```

Even though i have declared sum as static than also when i am printing printf("%d\n",sum); for every call than the last modified value gets printed!..

How should i print the value for every call? Why is my method not working?

Comment: That is the feature of `static`, nothing is wrong.

Comment: That is exactly how the `static` keyword is supposed to behave: the variable's value is kept between calls. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Just remove `static` keyword then you will get new value of `sum` each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need a local variable without the `static` keyword.
This way each function call preserves its local copy of `sum`.

Comment: If you remove `static` then the method will not give correct result for `Russian Peasant algorithm`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have called the printf() at end of the function, the printf() executes in reverse chronological order & since sum is a static variable, it always prints the final sum value.

To print the Sum calculation in each recursion, Try the following:

```
int russian_peasant(int a,int b)
{
    static int sum =0;
    printf("%d\n",sum);
    if(a>=1)
    {
        if(a%2!=0)
        {
            sum += (b);
            russian_peasant(a/2,b*2);
        }
        else
        { 
            russian_peasant(a/2,b*2);
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Put `printf` inside `if` will get exact values.

Comment: Yea @Navnath, Keeping printf() in if will print the sum value only when it changes. If we need the Sum value for every recursion, we can have it outside.

Comment: +1, Yes you are right, i mean to say `printf` work 2 times for final value, i just want to optimize it, but your solution is working fine as it depend on requirement so we cannot juge it.